# What was the flying instrument panel layout type behind the yoke onboard the Antonov 225?

Tags: antonov-225

Was the layout of the instrument panel considered to be basic T type and what were the instruments on it?
[image]

Does this image below shows the correct instruments on the instrument panel?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I understand you meant An-225. Its cockpit was almost identical to that of An-124, apart from the engine group.

Basically, yes, it's almost a standard T. The only difference is that on the right, apart from the altimeter, there is TCAS (+transponder) - the black square digital display. Vertical speed is further to the right (a bit higher for the captain).

```
ASI/Mach | AI  | TCAS | VSI
---------|-----|------|----
         | HSI | Alt  |
```

<sup>(Source: An-124 manual, but it's difficult to quote it directly: apart from being in Russian, it is laid out per sub-system, and there is no united dash description).</sup>