# Does a Antonov An-225 have a Turn and Bank Indicator?

Tags: flight-instruments, antonov-225

May I know if there are any turn and bank indicators on the pilots instrument panel and where is it located at?

Comment: Related: [What was the flying instrument panel layout type behind the yoke onboard the Antonov 225?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/93450/what-was-the-flying-instrument-panel-layout-type-behind-the-yoke-onboard-the-ant)

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out in other posts, the top right instrument, appears to be a VSI (white needle) with an overlaid bank indicator (gold dial) over a ball slip/skid indicator.

Comment: That's not a VSI, the scale is wrong and it doesn't have a negative indication for descent. I have a Cuban friend who trained in Russia, I will ask him what it is.

Comment: It goes 10-20-30 clockwise, and 10-20-30 counter-clockwise, as a VSI would.  You posted the picture!  ;)  See also https://i.stack.imgur.com/liZTS.png

Comment: Turns out you nailed it. Combo VSI with an appropriate range for the behemoth's performance, with turn and bank. My friend Guajirovich confirmed it. 

Comment: And sadly, these questions and comments are all worded present tense.  The An-225 *had* a turn and bank.  :(

Comment: Nah. Has. The second one is going to be finished. https://www.cnn.com/travel/article/antonov-an-225-kiev-ukraine/index.html

Comment: Can you please explain how come an instrument that relies on dynamic pressure can account for gyroscopic reading ?. The turn indicator is intuitively put with the attitude indicator at the middle.

Comment: @UshbyTechnicalTeam presumably the device has both a canted bank gyro AND a connection to to the static ports inside the same enclosure.  Your intuition is correct, there’d be no way to accomplish both objectives with just one mechanism.

Comment: There is no reason an instrument cannot have both a gyro and a static air pressure mechanism.

Comment: @Ushby, this _is_ a combined gyro+air (btw, _static_ pressure, not dynamic) instrument. [This one](https://zaprib.ru/catalog/serijnoe-proizvodstvo/aviacionnaya-tehnika/kombinirovannyj-pribor-variometr-s-ukazatelem-povorota-i-skolzheniya-tipa-da/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. Top right instrument is a combination VSI and turn and bank.

[image: AN225 Captain's primary flight instruments]

Comment: Are you sure that that's not only a slip and skid indicator ? the VSI is a pitot static reading, how come it's combined with a gyroscope ? I am not sure about your answer, sir. Do you have manual reference ?

Comment: From my point of view it makes sense to have a combined instrument. When you are trying to make a coordinated turn often you want to maintain your altitude, or maintain a stable sink or climb rate. It makes sense to me to have that information centralized in one instrument. The part immediately above the center of the instrument is the bank indicator. As far as I know, the POH for the AN-225 is not publicly available. At least I have not been able to find it.

Comment: @Juan, at least An-124 POH is available (but in Russian as scanned pages), and it has an almost identical panel. Yes, this is a combined VSI and turn-and-bank indicator. It is designated ДА-30 ([example](https://zaprib.ru/catalog/serijnoe-proizvodstvo/aviacionnaya-tehnika/kombinirovannyj-pribor-variometr-s-ukazatelem-povorota-i-skolzheniya-tipa-da/)).